# mysql - SHA() method gives different result for same value of binary type with different sizes

Tags: sql, mysql, sha1

SHA() method giving different result for same value of binary with different sizes.

1. Created a table, columns with X1 binary(1), X2 binary(10) size.

> CREATE TABLE TEST_binary10_2 ( PK bigint NOT NULL, VERSION int NOT NULL, X1 binary(1) DEFAULT NULL, X2 binary(10) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`));

2. Inserted same text for both the columns.

> insert into TEST_binary10_2  values(2, 1, 3, 3);

3. Tried to retrieve SHA() for both, it returns different value even though it is same value.

> SELECT  PK, X1, X2, SHA(X1), SHA(X2) FROM TEST_binary10_2;

Result: you can observe SHA(X1) and SHA(X2) is different even though X1, and X2 contains same string. I want to know the reason and a solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql> select hex(x1), hex(x2) from test_binary10_2;
+---------+----------------------+
| hex(x1) | hex(x2)              |
+---------+----------------------+
| 33      | 33000000000000000000 |
+---------+----------------------+
```

This shows that the two binary strings are not the same. They have different lengths. The latter column is bound to be a 10-byte string of bytes, because the `BINARY` type is fixed length, and it will pad with zeroes if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `VARBINARY` instead of `BINARY`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

> When `BINARY` values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad value to the specified length. The pad value is `0x00` (the zero byte). Values are right-padded with `0x00` for inserts, and no trailing bytes are removed for retrievals. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` operations. 0x00 and space differ in comparisons, with 0x00 sorting before space.

> For `VARBINARY`, there is no padding for inserts and no bytes are stripped for retrievals. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` operations. `0x00` and space differ in comparisons, with `0x00` sorting before space.

You're comparing `3` against `3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`. If you look closely, you can see this in your output screenshot; the X2 column is much wider than it has to be, whereas all the other columns fit their (visible) contents.

Comment: Is there a way to remove right padding before generating SHA(). 
I am trying to compare data from two tables using SHA() – I cont change table data types.

Comment: @vasu You can do something like `SHA(TRIM(TRAILING CHAR(0x00) FROM X2))`, but depending on your actual binary data that might not be a good idea, and it'd be quite inefficient on a large table.